# Rails Active Record TimeZones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone, rails-activerecord

I have set the default time zone of my application to Pacific Time.

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

The problem I am facing is that when I query in rails console..for example

```
Transaction.last
```

it returns an object like this

```
=> #<Transaction id: 4926, offer_id: 4926, date: "2014-10-08 04:23:03", reference: "CBRNCUQU", driver_id: 464, driver_type: "User", amount: 80.0, status: "paid", created_at: "2014-10-08 04:23:03", updated_at: "2014-10-07 22:15:27">
```

The date field shown here is `date: "2014-10-08 04:23:03"` which is in UTC and actually the date now in PDT is 2014-10-07

But if I query like this `Transaction.last.date` it returns

```
Tue, 07 Oct 2014 21:23:03 PDT -07:00
```

which is correct and expected output

The problem that I am facing is,I want to display the details of the current days transaction in my page and it returns a transaction with future date in my page.This might be happening because the DB saves the records in UTC
Is there any way that I could fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from the api documentation http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_timezone/class

`default_timezone` only accepts `:local` or `:utc`

Comment: default_timezone is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v3.2.13) is shown here.